# Databricks Deduplicaton PySpark Code Removing All Rows in Table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I was given assistance with dedupe question I had to remove duplicate rows in databricks with Pyspark.

The dataframe that I execute the code on is as follows:

| Id | createdon | SinkModifiedOn | title | caltype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e64650d3-94fb-ec11-82e6-0022481b14fc | 04/07/2022 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 8b97aa35-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| bd97aa35-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 17/01/2023 18:08:12 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 42b5f518-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 17/01/2023 18:08:12 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 8ab2abf9-6169-ec11-8943-000d3a870a5b | 30/12/2021 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Basic |
| 2d51010f-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 40e1feb7-efa5-e811-a96b-00224800cdc2 | 22/08/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| d3320875-1e81-e811-a95c-00224800cc97 | 06/07/2018 | 17/01/2023 18:08:12 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 1ea0055a-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 81cf613f-1e81-e811-a95c-00224800cc97 | 06/07/2018 | 17/01/2023 18:08:12 | Partner | Enterprise |
| fb50010f-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| af4a3b88-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c4f1 | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 0551010f-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 8c20f753-5a78-e811-a95b-00224800c3e8 | 25/06/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| e597aa35-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 0adad377-b039-e911-a999-00224800c9f4 | 26/02/2019 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 3315cd94-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c4f1 | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 151ca1a8-a586-e811-a95c-00224800c4f1 | 13/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 55ce798d-2081-e811-a95c-00224800cc97 | 06/07/2018 | 17/01/2023 18:08:12 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 55ce798d-2081-e811-a95c-00224800cc97 | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 13:37:09 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 6fa9fe08-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 8197aa35-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 4151010f-1d81-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |
| 74cf613f-1e81-e811-a95c-00224800cc97 | 06/07/2018 | 16/01/2023 14:37:14 | Partner | Enterprise |

The Pyspark code is as follows:

The PySpark is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

df2 = partdf.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Id","CreatedOn").orderBy("SinkModifiedOn")))
df3 = df2.filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
```

After executing the code absolutely no rows are returned.

Can someone take a look at the code at let me know why after deduping no rows are returned?

My guess is that it has something to do with the `SinkModified` on field

Comment: Can you share how you created dataframe and its schema?

Comment: Are you using Databricks in any cloud platform (if yes, specify)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dropDuplicates` to remove duplicate rows :

```
df = partdf.dropDuplicates(subset=['Id', 'createdon', 'SinkModifiedOn', 'caltype'])
```

Or

in this specific case, just simply:

```
partdf.drop_duplicates()
```